# torch.utils.ffi is deprecated. How to use cpp extensions instead?

Tags: python, torch

I am trying to run code that is using wrap_function from torch.utils.ffi (which has deprecated). I am struggling to figure out how to use cpp extensions instead as suggested by the error message, can any anyone help please?

The code I need to replace:

```
from torch.utils.ffi import _wrap_function
from ._nms import lib as _lib, ffi as _ffi

__all__ = []
def _import_symbols(locals):
    for symbol in dir(_lib):
        fn = getattr(_lib, symbol)
        if callable(fn):
            locals[symbol] = _wrap_function(fn, _ffi)
        else:
            locals[symbol] = fn
        __all__.append(symbol)

_import_symbols(locals())
```

I have tried running the code in both python 3.6 and python 2.7, see error message below,

```
  File "build.py", line 3, in <module>
    from torch.utils.ffi import create_extension
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/ffi/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    raise ImportError("torch.utils.ffi is deprecated. Please use cpp extensions instead.")
ImportError: torch.utils.ffi is deprecated. Please use cpp extensions instead.
```

Comment: And what does this have to do with C#?

Answer (score 2):

Check

```py
from torch.utils.cpp import ....
#or
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import ....
#or
from torch.utils.cpp_extension_versioner import...
```

it looks good at my PC

Comment: thanks Mateusz. I had previously tried torch.utils.cpp_extension but this did not work, for now I have downgraded my torch version to 0.4.1 and it runs ok. But I will keep in mind to try torch.utils.cpp and torch.utils.cpp_extension_versioner if I have the same problem in the future