# How can I solve "torch.utils.ffi is deprecated. Please use cpp extensions instead" without downgrade pytorch version?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

When I run the code below it shows me the error.
`ImportError: torch.utils.ffi is deprecated. Please use cpp extensions instead.`
I have been searching solution on the online. The problem is the code below working in old version of torch (0.4.1). I want to know whether it is possible to modify or replace this code for working in the new version of pytorch.

```
from torch.utils.ffi import _wrap_function
from ._nms import lib as _lib, ffi as _ffi

__all__ = []
def _import_symbols(locals):
    for symbol in dir(_lib):
        fn = getattr(_lib, symbol)
        if callable(fn):
            locals[symbol] = _wrap_function(fn, _ffi)
        else:
            locals[symbol] = fn
        __all__.append(symbol)

_import_symbols(locals())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [torch.utils.ffi is deprecated. How to use cpp extensions instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57491279/torch-utils-ffi-is-deprecated-how-to-use-cpp-extensions-instead)

Comment: I already tried it but it is error with _wrap_function. it shows like this: `ImportError: cannot import name '_wrap_function' from 'torch.utils.cpp_extension'`

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem have just seen some useful information in:

- https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html
- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cpp_extension.html

To avoid downgrade the version of PyTorch, you should consider to use the following libraries while finding more details in the above links:

```
from setuptools import setup
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension, CppExtension
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you comment. I will check it.